# The post is not displaying with WP_Query

Tags: php, wordpress

```
<?php $loop = new WP_Query(array('post_type'=>'works', 'orderby' => 'post_id', 'order'=>'ASC')) ?>

<?php while($loop->haveposts()): $loop->the_post(); ?>

    <?php echo the_post(); ?>
    <a href="https:www.mindificent.in" alt="mindificent" target="_blank">
        <?php  echo the_post(); ?>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="item-image">
                <img src="img/items/item5.png" alt="" />
            </div>
            <div class="item-text">
                <div class="item-text-wrap">
                    <p class="item-text-category"><?php echo the_title() ?></p>
                    <h2 class="item-text-title"><?php echo the_field('work_desc') ?></h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>

    // This is the code for displaying custom post

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: You're missing a `;` at the end of the first line (should be right before the closing `?>` tag.) It might be a good idea to enable [WordPress' Debugging mode](https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/), it'll help you spot these kind of issues faster.

Comment: Thanks I added ; but still not displaying and enabled wordpress debugging mode also

Comment: Another error in your code: `$loop->haveposts()` should be `$loop->have_posts()` instead. Again, checking the `debug.log` file will show you what the problems in your code are.

Comment: Thanks it worked the have_posts :) Blunder My mistake

Answer (score 1):

Use this Code

```
<?php 

    $args = array('post_type' => 'works', 'post_status' => 'publish', 'orderby' => 'post_id', 'order' => 'ASC');

    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );

    if( $loop->have_posts() ) 
    {
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) 
        {
            $loop->the_post();
            ?>
            <a href="https:www.mindificent.in" alt="mindificent" target="_blank">
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="item-image">
                        <img src="img/items/item5.png" alt="" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="item-text">
                        <div class="item-text-wrap">
                            <p class="item-text-category"><?php echo the_title() ?></p>
                            <h2 class="item-text-title"><?php echo the_field('work_desc') ?></h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>

            <?php
        }
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>
```

if the_title() function not work then you could try:

```
<p class="item-text-category"><?php echo get_the_title() ?></p>
```